# Fedex API. Shipping rates request for Multiple-Package Shipment rates

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, php, magento-enterprise, fedex

I am looking for fedex shipping rates (shipping estimate quotes), how to add multiple package(box) shipping rates after certain weight limit.

I know there is option in magento admin panel weight limit but shipping charges are not coming properly after certain limit cross.

Basic query is how to add multiple boxes or packages in api request.

example 1 package holds only 12 items and all items weight is similar.

Thanks.

Comment: hey @shyam. Did you got any idea to do this. If you found something related to it then post your answer. I am also looking for this idea. But not getting any solution. Help me if you have any thought.